# Is $[n]_q!$ invertible in $\mathbb C [[h]]\ $?

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, deformation-quantization

Consider the Hopf algebra $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ over the ring $\mathbb C [[h]]$ generated by $E, F, H$ and relations $:$

$$[H, E] = 2 E,\ \ [H, F] = - 2 F,\ \ [E, F] = \frac {q^H - q^{-H}} {q - q^{-1}}$$ where $q = e^h = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac {h^n} {n!} \in \mathbb C [[h]].$ The comultiplication $\Delta,$ the counit $\varepsilon$ and the antipode $S$ on $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ are defined as follows $:$

$$\Delta (E) = E \otimes q^H + 1 \otimes E, \ \ \Delta (F) = F \otimes 1 + q^{-H} \otimes F, \\ \Delta (H) = H \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H,$$

$$\varepsilon (E) = 0, \ \ \varepsilon (F) = 0, \ \ \varepsilon (H) = 0,$$

$$S (E) = - E q^{-H}, \ \ S (F) = - q^H F, \ \ S (H) = - H.$$

This can be easily shown to be a quantization of the standard Lie bialgebra structure of $sl_2 (\mathbb C).$

In Etingof's lecture notes it is claimed that $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ is a quasitriangular Hopf algebra with universal $R$-matrix being given by $$R = q^{\frac 1 2 H \otimes H} \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} q^{\frac {n (n - 1)} {2}} \frac {(q - q^{-1})^n} {[n]_q!} E^n \otimes F^n$$ where $q = e^h$ and $$\begin{align*} [n]_q! & = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n} \frac {q^k - q^{-k}} {q - q^{-1}} \\ & = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n} (q^{k - 1} + q^{k - 3} + \cdots + q^{- k + 1}) \end{align*}$$ which is known as the $q$-factorial of the $q$-integer $[n]_q$ corresponding to $n \in \mathbb N.$

Now my question is $:$

**Question** $:$ What is $\frac {1} {[n]_q!}$ in the expression of $R\ $? How to view it as an element of $\mathbb C [[h]]\ $?

Any suggestion in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

**Source** $:$ *Lectures on Quantum Groups* by Pavel Etingof and Oliver Schiffmann.

---

**EDIT** $:$ In order for the expression of $R$ to make sense we need to know what is $[0]_q !\ $? Then we need to invert it. This is something which is not defined.

Comment: For each $q$-integer use $(q-q^{-1})/(q^k - q^{-k}) = -q^{k-1} (q^2 -1)\cdot 1/(1 - q^{2k})$ and expand the last part as a geometric series. Does that help?

Comment: @JulesLamers$:$ Hmm it makes sense. But I don't think it's easy to show that $R$ is a quasitriangular structure on $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ although I haven't computed it yet. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: I don't think it is invertible in the ring, but perhaps the ratio in which it enters in the formula for the R-matrix makes sense.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk$:$ How? Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: @PeterKravchuk$:$ In order for the expression of $R$ to make sense we need to somehow invert $\left (q- q^{-1} \right )$ in $\mathbb C[[h]].$ Is it always possible?

Comment: @PeterKravchuk$:$ The only problem occurs when $n = 0.$

Comment: @PeterKravchuk$:$ How to divide the numerator by $\left ( q - q^{-1} \right )$ in the expression of $[E, F]\ $?

Comment: @JulesLamers$:$ How to divide the numerator by $\left (q - q^{-1} \right )$ in the expression of $[E, F]\ $?

Comment: By the way, if you're looking for help with an exercise, please instead post your question, along with your attempt, at mathematics.stackexchange

Comment: @JulesLamers$:$ $1/(1 - q^{2k})$ can't be written as a formal power series in $h$ over $\mathbb C.$ What is the coefficient of $h\ $? Isn't it infinite?

Comment: @JulesLamers$:$ Then this idea won't work. Actually the expression of $R$ in $\mathbb C [[h]]$; not the one I proposed.

Comment: By direct computation, the combination $q^{n(n-1)/2} (q-q^{-1})^n/[n]_q!$ expands as $\tfrac{2^n}{n!} (q-1)^n \, \big(1 + \tfrac{n(n-2)}{2}(q-1) + O(q-1)^2 \big)$, yielding a formal power series in $h$ of the form $\tfrac{2^n}{n!} h^n \, \big(1 + \tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}h + O(h^2)\big)$. There is no problem. Work out examples for low $n$ to see how this works.

Comment: @JulesLamers$:$ I already have that.

Comment: So what's the remaining problem / question then?

Comment: PS. To answer the question in your edit: by definition $[0]_q! =1$ (empty product), just like $0!=1$.